# Visual Studio Code Won't auto complete my C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**SOLVED**

Just to clarify this is about **VS code** not just **VS**

I've had the worst 3 hours looking for anything that could possibly fix my Visual studio code. I'm using the program to develop a game on unity but I can't seem to get the auto complete thing (I think its  Intellisense) to auto complete my code causing spelling mistakes and making coding 10x longer than it needs to take.

Heres a list of things I have tried:

- Install .Net Framework v4.7.1 (which is what the console says to do)
- Fix the Assembly file made by unity multiple time
- Reinstall Visual studio, C# plugin and .Netframework
- Change the OmniSharp to the latest version

I will add that when ever I type anything it comes up with **"[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService Could not find document for file c:\Users\Bruhman\Grinder\Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs"**
and when I open visual studios and write anything in the script it'll come up with an error that states **"Some Projects have trouble loading. "Source: C# (Extension)" "**

Below is a screen shot of what comes up in the console (It's the same every time)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3gr8.png)

Comment: First thing to clarify: is this Visual Studio Code, or Visual Studio? They're entirely different products. I suspect it's Visual Studio Code, given the screenshot... please update your post to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind I found out the issue, apparently I need to install Visual Studios Community version and then the .Net developer packs from visual studios and not just online, I'm assuming that it doesn't get detected or something when installed through the exe file...

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know much, but I use it every day : have you tried the unity tools extension ?

It features a lot and also the c# auto completion.

If it still bugs, have you installed the .Net for the EXACT version. I also struggled because I had the upper version and not the exact.

Finally is it linked with unity (I don't know if it could interfere if not done)

Sorry I don't know anything else if this don't work.

Comment: I have used the unity tool extension (didn't do anything), I uninstalled all .Net framework files from my pc and reinstalled the v4.7.1 cause that's what the console and some forms said, I'm not sure what you mean exactly by linked to unity, I have linked VSC to unity through the pref menu but that might not be what you're talking about